# Flutter and Firestore: NoSuchMethodError: The method '...' was called on null

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

i have a login page in my flutter app to authenticate and register users. When i want to save the user email-address to firestore (after register), i get the error:

```
flutter: Error: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'saveRegisterUserData' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: saveRegisterUserData(email: "test@test.de", userID: "EVDnVFMkYeYd291Yzu2j2r8HLpC2")'
```

i have created a seperate dart-file for the Firestore Functions. It look like this:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:async';

abstract class BaseFire {
Future <void> saveRegisterUserData({String userID, String email});
}

class Fire implements BaseFire {
 final Firestore firestore = new Firestore();
 DocumentReference usersdocuments;

 Future <void> saveRegisterUserData({String userID, String email}) async {
   usersdocuments = Firestore.instance.collection("Users").document(userID);
   Map<String, String> registerdata = <String, String>{
   "Email": email,
   };
   usersdocuments.setData(registerdata).whenComplete(() {
   return print("Document Added");
   }).catchError((error) => print(error));
 }
}
```

i import this file in my login page und execute this function:

```
import '../Firebase/firestore.dart';

class SignInPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SignInPage({this.firestore});
  final BaseFire firestore;

@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
  return _SignInPageState();
  }
}

class _SignInPageState extends State<SignInPage> {
   String _email;
   String _password;

 ...

 void submitRegister() async {
   if (validateAndSave()) {
     try {
       String userId = await widget.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
       await widget.firestore.saveRegisterUserData(userID: userId, email: _email);
      } catch (error) {
        print(error);
     }
    }
   }
}
```

Where is my mistake? Thank you for our help

Answer (score 1):

You have Automatic Class Member Variable Initialization at

```
SignInPage({this.firestore});
```

{} make the parameter optional and unless you truly mean to make your

```
firebase //variable
```

optional or have default value don't enclose it in {} just remove it. You will get any error message where you have used your SignInPage,just fix the parameter and hopefully things will work fine.

Comment: i tried this:

`SignInPage ( [this.firestore] );`
`final BaseFire firestore;`

But i always get the same issue...

Comment: just SingInPage(this.firestore); and pass in your BaseFire when you initialize your SignInPage. Your firestore is null at that point which means you possible haven't passed it through constructor because the BaseFire variable is optional there.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. I am a new developer and i am not sure, what i do now...sorry. So my constructor looks like this: SignInPage([BaseFire firestore]); and my firestore variable looks like this: final BaseFire firestore; It is right or what must i do?

Comment: Try this: SignInPage(this.firestore); //no [] here. When you initialize your SignInPage you can just pass in the BaseFire baseFire = new BaseFire() //intizaling your BaseFire variable. When you use your widget just write SignInPage(baseFire);

Comment: many thanks for your help, but i get another error, when try BaseFire baseFire = new BaseFire(). Dart say: "Abstract classes can't be created with a 'new' expression... What can we do?

Comment: i solve the problem... i created this variable: final BaseFire firestore = new Fire(); and that works... thank you for your time and for your help... Niklas